# Filter Named Keys by Date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to filter data between dates but I can't perform the filter due to complexity.

please help me mongo DB aggregate query

I have to pass the start date and end date and it should return

```
{
    col1: {
        12 - 02 - 2019: val1,
        14 - 02 - 2019: val3
    },
    col2: {
        12 - 02 - 2019: val1,
        14 - 02 - 2019: val3
    },
    col3: {
        12 - 02 - 2019: val1,
        14 - 02 - 2019: val3
    }
}
```

here is my MongoDB document--------

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('65656222dss5ds'),
    data: {
        col1: {
            '12-07-2012': 'value1',
            '13-07-2012': 'value2',
            '14-07-2012': 'value3',
            '15-07-2012': 'value5'
        },
        col2: {
            '12-07-2012': 'value1',
            '13-07-2012': 'value2',
            '14-07-2012': 'value3',
            '15-07-2012': 'value5'
        },
        col3: {
            '12-07-2012': 'value1',
            '13-07-2012': 'value2',
            '14-07-2012': 'value3',
            '15-07-2012': 'value5'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? Please, consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing your question.

Comment: DO you have any opportunity to fix that data design?  You have dates as strings as keys (lvals).   You cannot easily query on that, never mind the agg.   Your docs would be much better served like `{date: ISODate("20121207"), value: "value1" }`  Then your queries become easy.

Comment: No the date is in string format only

Answer (score 1):

I approached this like an Inverted Obfuscated C challenge:  Given challenging data and a desired output ... how?

```
c = db.foo.aggregate([
// Start the journey of turning lvals into rvals...                          
{$project: {x: {$objectToArray: "$$CURRENT.data"}}}

// ... and do it again!                                                      
,{$project: {QQ: {$map: {
                input: "$x",
                as: "z",
                in: {
                    vv: {$objectToArray: "$$z.v"},
                    colk: "$$z.k"
                }
            }}
    }}

// At this point we have no more lvals of interest, but we have too          
// many arrays.  Let's simplify and turn it into individual docs:            
,{$unwind: "$QQ"}

// At this point we have a bunch of docs where QQ.colk is the collection     
// key and QQ.vv is an array of (k,v) value pairs of (string date, value):    
//    {                                                                      
//      "_id" : 1,                                                         
//      "QQ" : {                                                           
//        "vv" : [                                                           
//          {"k" : "12-07-2012",  "v" : "value44"},                          
//          {"k" : "13-07-2012",  "v" : "value45"},                          
//          {"k" : "14-07-2012",  "v" : "value46"},                          
//          {"k" : "15-07-2012",  "v" : "value47"                            
//           ],                                                              
//        "colk" : "col3"                                                    
//        }                                                                  
//   }                                                                       
//       
// OK.  Now it is time to turn those DD-MM-YYYY strings into dates so we     
// can do a proper filter.  We do so by running the QQ.vv array through      
// the $map function and using $dateFromParts + $substr to make a date.      
// Note that we "reuse" projected field QQ (i.e. input was QQ and the        
// project is QQ, sort of like saying QQ = f(QQ) ) and just keep carrying    
// along colk:                                                               
,{$project: {QQ: {$map: {
                input: "$QQ.vv",
                as: "z",
                in: {
                    v: "$$z.v",
                    d: {$dateFromParts : {
                            "year":  {$toInt: {$substr: ["$$z.k",6,4]}},
                            "month": {$toInt: {$substr: ["$$z.k",3,2]}},
                            "day":   {$toInt: {$substr: ["$$z.k",0,2]}}
                        }}
                }
            }},
             colk: "$QQ.colk"
    }}


// We now have filterable dates in an array associated with colk.            
// Now we can filter!  I hardcode the dates here but it should be clear this is
// where variables would come into play:                                                  
,{$project: {QQ: {$filter: {
                input: "$QQ",
                as: "zz",
                cond: { $and: [
{$gt: [ "$$zz.d", new ISODate("20120713") ]},
{$lt: [ "$$zz.d", new ISODate("20120716") ]}
                               ]}
            }},
             colk: "$colk"
    }}



// Almost home!   Now: reconstitute the collection key (colk):               
,{$group: {_id: "$colk", members: {$push: "$QQ"} }}

   ]);
```

Now at this point, each doc had an _id corresponding to a unique collection key (col1, col2, col3).  members is an array of arrays.  The OP doesn't say a lot about date overlap
and such but that's OK.   Hopefully you grok it from here:

````
{                                                                            
  "_id" : "col1",                                                            
  "members" : [                                                              
    [                                                                        
      {                                                                      
        "v" : "value3",                                                      
        "d" : ISODate("2012-07-14T00:00:00Z")                                
      },                                                                     
      {                                                                      
        "v" : "value5",                                                      
        "d" : ISODate("2012-07-15T00:00:00Z")                                
      }                                                                      
    ],                                                                       
    [                                                                        
      {                                                                      
        "v" : "value22",                                                     
        "d" : ISODate("2012-07-14T00:00:00Z")                                
      },                                                                     
      {                                                                      
        "v" : "value23",                                                     
        "d" : ISODate("2012-07-15T00:00:00Z")                                
      }                                                                      
    ]                                                                        
  ]                                                                          
}                                                                          ```
````

Comment: Nicely done. You really should avoid creating multiple pipeline stages that do the same thing ( such as the `$project` ) in succession where they could be one. You also could have used `$toDate` which does in fact recognize `dd-mm-YYYY`. And you actually missed the part of the question that was about using the input object to create the query. Not exactly what the OP asked for but a good try

Comment: True on multiple pipes!   Sometimes I do this with the "bigger" functions to incrementally show what is happening, as newcomers to MQL sometimes cannot follow `$filters` of `$maps` of `$maps`, etc.   I thought the OP said he needed to pass in start and end date , not get it from input doc....?
But in the end:  your comprehensive answer below nails the point:  we want to be using values in the design, not keys.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, your real issue here is related to how the data has been structured. Being that whilst organizing and accessing things by *named keys* is usually preached as an optimal pattern for data access in client side code, the exact *opposite* applies for databases in general, and MongoDB is no exception.

Databases basically want *values* to perform searches on instead of *keys*, and for this reason you actually need to change all the data via a run-time coercion from the *keys* into *values* in order to filter it the way you want.

That said, here's a listing which shows the approaches:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

// Basic logging helper
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

// Sample document
const data = {
  data: {
    col1: {
      '12-07-2012': 'value1',
      '13-07-2012': 'value2',
      '14-07-2012': 'value3',
      '15-07-2012': 'value5'
    },
    col2: {
      '12-07-2012': 'value1',
      '13-07-2012': 'value2',
      '14-07-2012': 'value3',
      '15-07-2012': 'value5'
    },
    col3: {
      '12-07-2012': 'value1',
      '13-07-2012': 'value2',
      '14-07-2012': 'value3',
      '15-07-2012': 'value5'
    }
  }
};

// Sample input conditions
const input = {
  col1: {
    '12-07-2012': 'value1',   // clearly pairs of "from" and "to"
    '14-07-2012': 'value3'
  },
  col2: {
    '12-07-2012': 'value1',
    '14-07-2012': 'value3'
  },
  col3: {
    '12-07-2012': 'value1',
    '14-07-2012': 'value3'
  }
};

// Helper for converting strings to valid ISO dates
const toDate = dateStr => new Date(dateStr.split("-").reverse().join("-"));

//  Helper for the $filter arguments for $or
const makeCond = input => Object.entries(input)
  // get key and value pairs of object and make an array per 'key'
  .map(([k,v]) =>
    ({
      // Reduce the v objects as key value pairs into a single array
      '$and': Object.entries(v).reduce((o, [k,v], i) =>
        [
          ...o,     // spread the reduced array

          // Add and spread these new array elements
          ...[
            // Use $gte or $lte depending on current index
            { [(i == 0) ? '$gte' : '$lte']: [ '$$this.date', toDate(k) ] },
            { [(i == 0) ? '$gte' : '$lte']: [ '$$this.value', v ] }
          ]
        ],
        // The initial array for reduce
        [{ '$eq': [ '$$this.col', k ] }])
    })
  );

const makeOrCondition = input => Object.entries(input)
  .map(([col,v]) =>
    ({
      col,
      date: Object.keys(v).reduce((o,k,i) =>
        ({ ...o, [(i == 0) ? '$gte' : '$lte']: toDate(k) }), {}),
      value: Object.values(v).reduce((o,v,i) =>
        ({ ...o, [(i == 0) ? '$gte': '$lte']: v }), {})
    })
  );

(async function() {

  let client;

  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(url, opts);

    let db = client.db('test');

    await db.collection('example').deleteMany({});
    await db.collection('example').insertOne(data);

    // Debug the makeCond
    //log(makeCond(input));

    // Covert objects to arrays of arrays
    const mapObjects = {
      '$map': {
        'input': { '$objectToArray': '$data' },
        'in': {
          '$let': {
            'vars': { 'col': '$$this.k' },
            'in': {
              '$map': {
                'input': { '$objectToArray': '$$this.v' },
                'in': {
                  'col': '$$col',
                  'date': { '$toDate': '$$this.k' },
                  'value': '$$this.v'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // Flatten arrays of arrays to single array
    const joinArrays = {
      '$reduce': {
        'input': mapObjects,
        'initialValue': [],
        'in': { '$concatArrays': [ '$$value', '$$this' ] }
      }
    };

    // Apply the filter to the array elements
    const filterArray = {
      '$filter': {
        'input': joinArrays,
        'cond': { '$or': makeCond(input) }
      }
    };

    // Basically an inline version of $group
    const grouper = {
      '$reduce': {
        'input': filterArray,
        'initialValue': [],
        'in': {
          '$let': {
            'vars': { 'current': '$$this' },
            'in': {
              '$concatArrays': [
                //  Filter reduce output from the matching col
                { '$filter': {
                  'input': '$$value',
                  'cond': { '$ne': [ '$$current.col', '$$this.k' ] }
                }},
                // Conditionally join to:
                { '$cond': {
                  'if': {
                    '$ne': [
                      { '$indexOfArray': [
                        '$$value.k', '$$this.col'
                      ]},
                      -1
                    ]
                  },
                  // Concat the inner array where matched
                  'then': [{
                    'k': '$$this.col',
                    'v': {
                      '$concatArrays': [
                        { '$arrayElemAt': [
                          '$$value.v',
                          { '$indexOfArray': ['$$value.k', '$$this.col'] }
                        ]},
                        [{ 'k': '$$this.date', 'v': '$$this.value' }]
                      ]
                    }
                  }],
                  // Create the inner array where not matched
                  'else': [{
                    'k': '$$this.col',
                    'v': [{
                      'k': '$$this.date',
                      'v': '$$this.value'
                    }]
                  }]
                }}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    const pipeline = [
      { '$match': {
        '$expr': { '$gt': [{ '$size': filterArray }, 0] }
      }},
      { '$project': {
        'data': {
          '$arrayToObject': {
            '$map': {
              'input': grouper,
              'in': {
                // reformat
                'k': '$$this.k',
                'v': {
                  '$arrayToObject': {
                    '$map': {
                      'input': '$$this.v',
                      'in': {
                        'k': {
                          '$dateToString': {
                            'date': '$$this.k',
                            'format': '%d-%m-%Y'
                          }
                        },
                        'v': '$$this.v'
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }}
    ];

    log(pipeline);

    let result = await db.collection('example').aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
    log(result);

    // Create example2

    await db.collection('example').aggregate([
      { '$project': { 'data': joinArrays } },
      { '$out': 'example2' }
    ]).toArray();


    /*
     * Simple $elemMatch and $filter usage when already an array
     *
     */
    let result2 = await db.collection('example2').aggregate([
      { '$match': {
        'data': {
          '$elemMatch': {
            '$or': makeOrCondition(input)
          }
        }
      }},
      { '$project': {
        'data': {
          '$filter': {
            'input': '$data',
            'cond': { '$or': makeCond(input) }
          }
        }
      }}
    ]).toArray();

    log(result2);

    // Create example3
    await db.collection('example2').aggregate([
      { '$unwind': '$data' },
      { '$replaceRoot': { 'newRoot': '$data' } },
      { '$out': 'example3' }
    ]).toArray();

    /*
     * Really simple when the elements are discreet documents
     * in their own collection
     */

    let result3 = await db.collection('example3').find({
      '$or': makeOrCondition(input)
    }).toArray();

    log(result3);

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    if (client)
      client.close();
  }

})()
```

### Example 1

That's the main `aggregate()` listing which executes first and is basically what you are asking for. You will see the output of this produces the desired removal of the keys that did not meet the conditions provided in the `input` document:

```
  {
    "_id": "5d6a7ac8736dce1c76d9d3e8",
    "data": {
      "col1": {
        "12-07-2012": "value1",
        "13-07-2012": "value2",
        "14-07-2012": "value3"
      },
      "col2": {
        "12-07-2012": "value1",
        "13-07-2012": "value2",
        "14-07-2012": "value3"
      },
      "col3": {
        "12-07-2012": "value1",
        "13-07-2012": "value2",
        "14-07-2012": "value3"
      }
    }
  }
```

How that basically gets done is using the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to remove elements from an *array* which does not meet conditions. But in order to do that you need to apply [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) in order to covert the *keys* into objects with `k` and `v` properties containing the *values* by the key and value of each property respectively. Note the section:

```
// Covert objects to arrays of arrays
const mapObjects = {
  '$map': {
    'input': { '$objectToArray': '$data' },
    'in': {
      '$let': {
        'vars': { 'col': '$$this.k' },
        'in': {
          '$map': {
            'input': { '$objectToArray': '$$this.v' },
            'in': {
              'col': '$$col',
              'date': { '$toDate': '$$this.k' },
              'value': '$$this.v'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Which is also using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in order to work through the elements and *map* the *inner* objects into arrays of `k` and `v` properties as well. Note also the [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) which is smart enough to recognize the `dd-mm-yyy` format of the string and covert into a BSON Date for comparison.

The other things to note is the usage of [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) in order to *flatten* the *arrays of arrays* produced by the nested structure ( shown as `joinArrays` ) and the actual [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) condition:

```
// Apply the filter to the array elements
const filterArray = {
  '$filter': {
    'input': joinArrays,
    'cond': { '$or': makeCond(input) }
  }
};
```

The `makeCond()` here is actually implemented in order to turn the `input` sample from the question ( corrected in order to match the provided data ) into an actual expression to be used within the argument to `cond` for [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). You can look at the generated pipeline in the program output to see what that actually looks like, but that is the part that does the actual filtering.

You can also note the actual `pipeline` in use here only needs two pipeline stages, being a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in order to select only documents which would return keys still matching those conditions and a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) which does the actual work of removing the keys that do not meet conditions from the documents before returning the result.

Also note that the other parts with the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) are nested within the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) expression, and of course that this whole expression get's reused in both pipeline stages.

Within the actual [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) we use [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) in a different way in order to *group* the data back together ready for it's expected output form just like the original document. This could alternately be done with separate [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages, but doing that is nowhere near as efficient, even if it may be easier to read.

Other things to look for are the usage of [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) and [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) which aid in the *grouping* all within a [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) handling the `if/then/else` logic. It's another reduced array with inner array joining so [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) is also used here.

And finally in order to come back to the original object form with named keys the BSON Date values need to be converted to strings to be valid for a key name. The [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) operator accepts a `format` parameter with a `"%d-%m-%Y"` format string back to the original format.

It might all take a while to sink in, but those are the links and there are comments in the code. There would be more explanation but Stack Overflow only allows a limited amount of space for answers, and this approaches that limit. Read and run the example code to learn the details as well as consulting the referenced links to the main methods.

## Example 2

The code is basically there to show that the main *"lifting"* provided in the example with the direct answer to the question is basically all about transforming the document content into an array so the "dates" and other conditions can be filtered from the content.

The point of the "example 2" code is to show that when you instead structure the `data` property as an *array* to start with, then the query operations become way more simple and efficient.

At the very least you *should* always favor an *array* over *named keys* when your intention is to do filtering or any other query operations which would instead be on *values* rather than on *keys* just as mentioned in the opening statements.

## Example 3

This is basically there to demonstrate that if your only concern is working with the content of `data` within the document, then actually separating out these entries as discreet documents in their own collection makes for the most simple query form of all and by far the most efficient since nothing needs to be calculated at all and an index can be used for the whole process.

As discreet documents the process is in fact *query only* and needs no `aggregate()` processing at all. This makes it *fast*.

### Conclusion

Whilst most things are *possible* using the aggregation framework it's still not *always* the recommended solution. This should also demonstrate the importance of *design* in considering how your data will actually be used.

So in short, if you want to "query" anything in a meaningful way without introducing unnecessary overheads which will ruin application performance as well as greatly increase complexity of code maintenance, then use **values** instead of **keys** to identify those data points that are meaningful for use in that way instead.

Comment: very well explained. thanks. I have one query , in input you taken column but cols are dynamic , i can only pass start and end date. can you please help me where do i need to make changes